# Numerical function on redis list using lua

Tags: redis, lua, aggregate

I am new to lua and redis.  I am considering using redis to support some real time queries.  As a proof of concept and performance sanity test I summed values in a list.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.13-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

python script

```
import redis
import numpy as np


n = 1000000

redis_host = "localhost"
redis_port = 6379
redis_password = ""

arr = np.random.rand(n)

r = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password, decode_responses=True)
r.delete('mylist')
r.lpush('mylist', *arr.tolist())
print(np.sum(arr))

lua_sum = """
local result = redis.call('lrange', KEYS[1], 0, -1)
local sum = 0
for i=1, #result, 1 do
    sum = sum + result[i]
end
return tostring(sum)
"""

f = r.register_script(lua_sum)
print(f(keys=['mylist']))
```

Using ipython timeit, it takes a little over a second for the redis version.  I was (naively?) expecting at least an order of magnitude lower latency.  Is there anything extremely inefficient in the script?  Note I realize that this particular use case could be handled by preprocessing, but its just a simple start.

Edit
The timeit commands specifically are:

```
In [2]: %timeit f(keys=['mylist'])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.sum(arr)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Lua script calls `LRANGE` to get 1 million numbers from Redis, i.e. `LRANGE key, 0, -1`, which is very inefficient. Redis needs to read 1 million numbers from a list, and pass these data to Lua. That will take a long time.

Also, you are trying to `LPUSH` 1 million numbers to Redis in a single call, that's also a very bad idea, since it might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: I know pushing 1 million values in one shot is slow.  It is just setting up the scenario.  I know its different, but using np.sum takes ~1 ms, or 1000x faster.  I know there would be extra overhead, but was surprised it was so much, especially given I have often heard how fast Redis is.  I was hoping there was something wrong in my script.

Comment: Yes, Redis is fast. However, if you run some [slow command](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog), it might be slow, and `LRANGE key 0 -1` for a large list, is a slow command.

Comment: So since LRANGE is slow for very long lists, is there another approach which performs better?  Or is redis just a poor choice for this use case?

Comment: IMHO, I don't think Redis is the right choice for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually looking for is something like [`redis-benchmark`](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks). It's included in the distribution of redis.

From the command line `redis-cli`, I populated an otherwise empty instance of redis with a list like yours:

```
127.0.0.1:6379>eval "local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, 1 do sum = sum + result[i]; end; return tostring(sum);" 0
```

Then, I ran `redis-benchmark`:

```
$ redis-benchmark -n 100000 script load "local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, 1 do sum = sum + result[i]; end; return tostring(sum);"
script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, ====== script load local result = redis.call('lrange', 'mylist', 0, -1); local sum = 0; for i=1, #result, 1 do sum = sum + result[i]; end; return tostring(sum); ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.20 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

99.99% <= 1 milliseconds
100.00% <= 1 milliseconds
83263.95 requests per second
```

As you can see, the results are quite different than what you are showing. 100,000 invocations of the script were completed in 1.2 seconds.

I don't know why your tests showed significantly worse performance, but I can think of several possibilities:

1. Memory/processor restrictions in your docker image
2. network latency
3. overhead from the python-redis library you are using

But, fundamentally, you should not be using redis for processing-bound scripts. Since redis is single threaded, a lua script will block the execution of all other scripts until it completes.

I suggest you play around with redis-benchmark to get a better idea of how redis performs.